# Difference between %o and %O in console.log (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, console.log

This is more a matter of curiosity than a serious problem but in the MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#outputting_text_to_the_console) for console.log about string substitutions it says:

> %o or %O
> Outputs a JavaScript object. Clicking the object name opens more information about it in the inspector.

Is there any difference between %o and %O?  I haven't noticed anything obvious in chrome.  If not why do both exist? Just some old compatibility thing or is there a reason we have both?

Comment: I hope this isn't a duplicate but I tried searching multiple times and even with quotes all the results for %o and %O seemed to ignore the percent and just give me results about big O notation.

Comment: The only difference I seem to have found was [this post](https://dmitripavlutin.com/console-log-tips/) which states `%o` displays __Element is displayed with optimally useful formatting__ while `%O`  displays __Element is displayed with generic JavaScript object formatting__.

Comment: @Nick Parson's excellent answer below explains what the difference is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some slight differences between the two. From the [console standard](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-generic-javascript-object-formatting%E2%91%A0):

> 4. If specifier is %o, optionally let converted be current with optimally useful formatting applied.
> 5. If specifier is %O, optionally let converted be current with generic JavaScript object formatting applied.

The standard then describes the difference between *optimally useful formatting* and *generic JavaScript object formatting* [here](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#object-formats):

> An object with generic JavaScript object formatting is a potentially
> expandable representation of a generic JavaScript object. An object
> with optimally useful formatting is an implementation-specific,
> potentially-interactive representation of an object judged to be
> maximally useful and informative

One way to think about the difference between the two is `%O` is like using [`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dir) as this will log the object's *generic JavaScript object formatting*, showing you specific properties of the object, whereas using `%o` is like using [`console.dirxml()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dirxml) or regular `console.log()` as this will log the object in its *optimally useful formatting*, which can be a developer-friendly/simplified representation of the object. As a result, `%o` will usually give you what you're after, but `%O` can give you further details such as the object's properties.

You can see the difference in certain objects, below are some of these objects:

```js
const regex = /abc/;
console.group("Regex object");
console.log("optimally useful formatting (%%o): %o", regex);
console.log("generic JavaScript object formatting (%%O): %O", regex);
console.groupEnd();

const fn = () => "foo";
console.group("Function object");
console.log("optimally useful formatting (%%o): %o", fn);
console.log("generic JavaScript object formatting (%%O): %O", fn);
console.groupEnd();

const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
console.group("DOM node");
console.log("optimally useful formatting (%%o): %o", ul);
console.log("generic JavaScript object formatting (%%O): %O", ul);
console.groupEnd();
```

```html
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>
```

Output in Chrome console:

[image: Chrome console output for the above snippet that shows detailed properties for %O objects and friendly formatted objects for %o]

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly I should probably use %o everywhere as that says: hey show me whatever the coders for the JS engine felt was the most useful data display and only use %O if ….well can't think of a reason.

Comment: @PeterGerdes yes, %o would be something you use most often, if you need to see further properties of an object that you can't see usually in the console, then %O would work (eg: console.log("%O", /abc/); would give you properties about the regular expression you wouldn't usually see with %o, so it could potentially help if you need to do certain types of debugging)

Comment: Ohh, I see %o may leave out some info to be more useful ...I didn't quite understand you the first time but should have as it's clear in your example.  THANKS!!